# Multivariable multiplication in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sympy

No idea how to multiply two polynomials of different variable. Below is my code and running it on IPython.

```
from sympy import *
from numpy import *

m1 = poly1d([1,0,0,1], variable = 'x')
m2 = poly1d([1,0], variable = 'y')
p=m1*m2
print(p)
```

Expected result is a polynomial with variable x and y but below is my result.

```
   4
1 x + 1 x
```

Comment: can you include the expected result (if it's too hard to do by hand, give a more simple example)

Comment: on a sidenote, `from module import *`  is not the best way (see this [book](http://www.oreilly.com/programming/free/files/a-whirlwind-tour-of-python.pdf) page 67

Comment: expected result is (x^3+1)*y

Comment: From the documentation string _"variable : str, optional
    Changes the variable **used when printing** `p` from `x` to `variable`"_ (bold is mine,,,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now you're using `numpy.poly1d`, which doesn't seem to take the `variable=` into account. If you want to do it symbolicallly, you can use `sympy.Poly`

```
from sympy import Poly
from sympy.abc import x, y

m1 = Poly((1, 0, 0, 1), x)
m2 = Poly((1,0), y)
m1, m2
```

> (Poly(x**3 + 1, x, domain='ZZ'), Poly(y, y, domain='ZZ'))

```
m1 * m2
```

> Poly(x**3*y + y, x, y, domain='ZZ')

Comment: if I do m1*m2 multiplication, I'm getting multivariate polynomial polynomial of x and y. But I have to make y as constant. Is there any specific syntax available?